# Pandas: doing quantile normalization on a subset of a flattened dataset with replicates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, so please pardon my inexperience. It is hard to explain exactly what my question is off the bat, so instead I will walk you through an m.w.e. My question will be highlighted with the `>` markdown (i.e. yellow)

I have a flattened dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'label': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],                                        
        'ind_1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],        
        'out_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],                                    
        'out_2': [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],                                    
        'ind_2': ['z', 'z','y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'y']
        #, and a whole lot of other columns         
    })
    df.head()

    ind_1   ind_2   label   out_1   out_2
0   a   z   1   1   16
1   a   z   1   2   15
2   a   y   1   3   14
3   a   y   1   4   13
4   b   z   1   5   12
```

where `ind_1` and `ind_2` are two independent variables, and `out_1` and `out_2` are two measurements made in response to altering the independent variables.

In addition, there are technical replicates (in this case 2) for each combination of the independent variables.

I want to quantile normalize across `ind_1`  i.e. quantile normalize the data for `ind_1 == 'a'` and then again for `ind_1 == 'b'`.

So my road map for tackling the problem is as follows:

1. get the subset of the data to be quantile normalized across
2. take the mean of the technical replicates (in this case, we will take the median values of `out_1` and `out_2` grouped by `ind_2`)
3. quantile normalize this matrix
4. merge with other meta data (the other columns not shown for simplicity)
5. repeat 1-4 for all values of `ind_1`

## 1 get subset of data

```
sdf = df[df.ind_1 == 'a']
sdf.head()

    ind_1   ind_2   label   out_1   out_2
0   a   z   1   1   16
1   a   z   1   2   15
2   a   y   1   3   14
3   a   y   1   4   13
8   a   z   2   9   8
```

not so bad.

## 2 take mean of replicates

```
ind_2_means = sdf.groupby(['label', 'ind_2']).mean()


                out_1   out_2
label   ind_2       
1   y           3.5     13.5
    z           1.5     15.5
2   y           11.5    5.5
    z           9.5     7.5


intermediate = ind_2_means.reset_index()



    label   ind_2   out_1_mean  out_2_mean
0   1   y   3.5     13.5
1   1   z   1.5     15.5
2   2   y   11.5    5.5
3   2   z   9.5     7.5



piv = intermediate.pivot('label', 'ind_2')


        out_1_mean      out_2_mean
ind_2   y       z       y       z
label               
1       3.5     1.5     13.5    15.5
2       11.5    9.5     5.5     7.5
```

my [quantile normalization function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249980/5623899) requires this to be without hierarchy i.e.:

```
ind_2   out_1_mean_y    out_1_mean_z    out_2_mean_y    out_2_mean_z
label               
1       3.5     1.5     13.5    15.5
2       11.5    9.5     5.5     7.5
```

> Question 1: how can I convert `piv` to the above layout? (lets call this variable `piv_flattened`)

## 3 Quantile Normalization

```
qn = quantile_normalize(piv_flattened, ['out_1_mean_y', 'out_1_mean_z', 'out_2_mean_y', 'out_2_mean_z'])
```

# has same layout as piv_flattened, just quantile normalized

## 4 merge with original data

> how can I
>
> 1.) return from this layout to that of `intermediate` (e.g. split up the keys `out_1_mean_z` to `out_1_mean` and `z`) and
>
> 2.) merge this back with the original data?

This likely has to modify the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261582/5623899)

## 5 Repeat for other subsets

I will encapsulate 1-4 into a function

Other approaches are welcome and any optimizations (and explanations as to why they work) would be appreciated.

## Expected Outcome

this is the form of the expected output, there is redundancy as you have to broadcast the means, but this preserves the data in the other columns

```
    ind_1   ind_2   label   out_1   out_2 out_1_mean out_2_mean    ... <all-non-shown-columns>
0   a   z   1   1   16  <a_z_out_1_mean_qn>     <a_z_out_2_mean_qn>
1   a   z   1   2   15  <a_z_out_1_mean_qn>     <a_z_out_2_mean_qn>
2   a   y   1   3   14  <a_y_out_1_mean_qn>     <a_y_out_2_mean_qn>
3   a   y   1   4   13  <a_y_out_1_mean_qn>     <a_y_out_2_mean_qn>
4   b   z   1   5   12  <b_z_out_1_mean_qn>     <b_z_out_2_mean_qn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you 1st question

```
piv.columns=piv.columns.map('_'.join)
piv
Out[431]: 
       out_1_y  out_1_z  out_2_y  out_2_z
label                                    
1          3.5      1.5     13.5     15.5
2         11.5      9.5      5.5      7.5
```